# How to properly handle Onclick event, event for a button doesn't show alert.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am Trying for an Onclick event for a button but it doesn't show alert. Can anyone suggest me on how to properly handle on click event.

```
function sendGetData () {   
    $.ajax({

         type: 'GET',
         url: 'Refresh',
         success: function (data) {

             var trHTML = '';
             $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                 if(data[i].test_progress=="Complete")
                     {
           var buttonVar = ('<button id="btn11">'+"Clicking"+'</button>');                   
                    $("#btn11").click(function(){
                                    alert("The paragraph was not clicked."+i);
                                });
                     }
                 else
                     {
                    var buttonVar = ('<button   id="btn12">'+"Stoping"+'</button>');
                    $("#btn12").click(function(){

                                    alert("The paragraph was not clicked."+i);
                                });

                     }

                 trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i].test_type + 
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].device_id + 
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].make + '&nbsp'+data[i].model+
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].stack_name +
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].suite_name + 
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].test_progress + '<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'+data[i].tests_run+'/'+data[i].total_tests+
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].start_time + 
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].end_time +
                 '</td><td>' + buttonVar +
                 '</td></tr>';

                });
             $('#test1').append(trHTML);
             $('#test').hide();
             $('#show').show();       
         }
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listeners for the click event are being added before you add the element to the DOM. That doesn't work.

```
var trHTML = '';

trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i].test_type + 
'</td><td>' + data[i].device_id + 
'</td><td>' + data[i].make + '&nbsp'+data[i].model+
'</td><td>' + data[i].stack_name +
'</td><td>' + data[i].suite_name + 
'</td><td>' + data[i].test_progress + '<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'+data[i].tests_run+'/'+data[i].total_tests+
'</td><td>' + data[i].start_time + 
'</td><td>' + data[i].end_time +
'</td><td>' + buttonVar +
'</td></tr>';

$('#test1').append(trHTML);

$.each(data, function (i, item) {

   if(data[i].test_progress=="Complete")
   {
     var buttonVar = ('<button id="btn11">'+"Clicking"+'</button>');                   
     $("#btn11").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was not clicked."+i);
    });
 }
 else
 {
    var buttonVar = ('<button   id="btn12">'+"Stoping"+'</button>');
    $("#btn12").click(function(){

        alert("The paragraph was not clicked."+i);
    });

}
```

You can only assign a click event to an element that's already in the DOM. After `$('#test1').append(trHTML);`

Comment: This works but everytime the value i starts from 0 for every button but in my table i need the row to start from thier particular index

Comment: I'm not entirely clear where this index you speak of fits into the code posted above, but it sounds like you need to store the index in a variable outside of this function so that it persists in between executions. I think  that is an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this method

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn12', function(event) {
 alert("The paragraph was not clicked."+i);
});
```

Comment: This works but everytime the value i starts from 0 for every button but in my table i need the row to start from thier particular index